# Application Pool Status in C#

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool

I am trying to get application pool status from within a web application. Application pool I am interested in is "ABC" but when I check for it by name I get nothing and when I inspect the available pools by name (i.e. manager.ApplicationPools) they show as Clr4ClassicAppPool, Clr4IntegratedAppPool, ... so I never find a match.

This is what I am using

```
public static int GetAppPoolStatus(string sAppPoolName)
{
    int iRet = -1;
    try
    {
        using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
        {
            ApplicationPool appPool = manager.ApplicationPools.FirstOrDefault(ap => ap.Name == sAppPoolName);

            if (appPool != null)
            {
                //Get the current state of the app pool
                iRet = (int)appPool.State;         // 0: Starting, 1: Started, 2: Stopping, 3: Stopped
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
    return iRet;
}
```

Comment: Here: `catch (Exception ex) { }` you tell the compiler: *"Please throw away any useful information that could help me find the cause of my problem."* Don't do that. :-)

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you running your app as Administrator?

Comment: A few possible causes: 1) You have IIS Express installed, and a wrong reference to `Microsoft.Web.Administration`. Then the above code runs against IIS Express, not full IIS. 2) There are exceptions caused by unknown reasons. In both cases, you can set break points to analyze further.

Comment: It does not throw any exceptions to catch. The problem is when I inspect manager.ApplicationPools I don't see any of the application pool names listed in IIS, just a list of generic pool names like I listed. "appPool" is always null because it does not find one with the name "ABC".

Comment: Do you see what you expect if you explicitly identify the host configuration you want? `new ServerManager(@"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config")`

Comment: I think @LexLi hit the nail on the head, seems like you are looking at IIS Express pools. Specify the path to the IIS config as I showed above.

Comment: Using path, I get "Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"; trying to debug from VS2019 in administrator mode. When I check the config file I do see app pool name. I will deploy to test server and see how it works there. But looks like Lex Li's comment was correct. I will post back.

Comment: Would someone make the comment about IIS Express into an answer and I will mark it? I deployed to test server and it works fine using full IIS.

Comment: @NoBullMan: *"It does not throw any exceptions to catch."* I understand that. It's still harmful, because if it *starts* throwing exceptions at some time in the future, it will just silently swallow them and you will not be informed that something is wrong. I know that this is not the question you asked, but I think it's important enough to warrant a comment.

Comment: @NoBullMan: As another side note, we generally prefer [mcve]s in SO questions. If your code does not throw any exceptions, the try-catch-block is irrelevent to the question and should be removed to make the code example "minimal" (just like the empty "else" block).

Comment: @Heinzi Thank you for the suggestions. I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GAC version (7.9.0.0) was part of IIS Express, and is resolved by MSBuild when compiling your project if your project file does not explicitly point to `%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll`.

The ultimate solution (if not to uninstall IIS Express) is to add a reference explicitly to `%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` to consume the right metadata at compile time. It has side effects, but still a reliable way. And at runtime, use assembly redirection to stick to version `7.0.0.0`.

More tips can be found in [this post](https://blog.lextudio.com/microsoft-web-administration-of-iis-express/)